# generated accessors to private fields of outer classes in java

Tags: java, inner-classes, accessor

So I have a question about the accessors generated by javac (version 1.7.0_65) to allow inner classes to access private fields of the outer class.

First, here is a short code snippet:

```
public class A {
    private int f = 0;

    class AA {
        public int m() {
            return f;
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler generates an accessor method in class A in order for method m to be able to read and return the value of f.

This accessor looks like this:

```
static int access$0(A);
    flags: ACC_STATIC, ACC_SYNTHETIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0       
         1: getfield      #12                 // Field f:I
         4: ireturn
```

And my question is: why is this accessor generated as a static method? Are there cases in which a non-static method wouldn't work?

Comment: @PatrickJAbareII His IDE isn't generating anything, javac is.

Answer (score 0):

This is because before your program loads for running there has to be any method in memory that will support your code(so that no compilation error will not occur). we know, static methods are loaded in memory before non-static members(variables and methods). Also,that accessor methods is invoked by JVM thread. JVM thread has access to static methods.

Answer (score 0):

IMO there are (at least) two reasons for this decision:

First: If the method was not static it would be possible that a subclass overrides it!

As the compiler cannot be sure that the classes at runtime are the same as seen at compilation time it is not able to generate a consistent disjoint naming.

Consider this example:

```
public class A {

    private int x = 1;

    private class AA {
        public int f() {
            return x; // would call access$0 on the outer instance
        }
    }
    public int getX() {
        return new AA().f();
    }
}
public class B extends A {

    private int y = 2;

    private class BB {
        public int g() {
            return y;
        }
    }
}
```

If the method was not static the following code would result in 2 instead of 1:

```
assertEquals(new B().getX(), 2);
```

Second: The accessor method must also be available for static inner classes.

Comment: Not sure how you get the result 2 in the example you have provided.

Comment: Because getting the field A.x in AA.f() would by compiled to a method invocation of the instance method access$0. And as access$0 would also be defined for B it would invoke B.access$0. That should just have been an example what would happen if the synthetic access method was not static.

Comment: Yes, but how would B.access$0 return 2?

Comment: Because access$0 is overwritten in B to return the field B.y

Comment: Have you confirmed this using javap? Because I don't see how it access$0 is overridden.

Comment: No. There should be another method B.access$0 that grants access to B.y from BB. As this method is static it is not overwritten! The example should just have shown what could happen if it was an instance method. Sorry, maybe it was too confusing.

Comment: I was confused when you say "access$0 is overwritten" as it is static. But also, I believe the generated byte code for B will be _static int access$0(B)_, not _static int access$0(A)_.

Comment: Sorry, it was probably too confusing. I wanted to show what would happen if you take the current approach and suppose that the methods were not static. The question was why the methods are static and I wanted to show what would happen if not.